# Detectar redirección en evento onLoad

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas, mi problemática es la siguiente:

Necesito saber en el evento onLoad de javascript si el navegador viene redireccionado o es la carga inicial de la página.

Un saludo.

Comment: No acabo de entender la diferencia entre "redireccionado" (supongo que te refieres a un HTTP 302 Redirect) y "carga inicial de la página"; cuando redireccionas también hay una "carga inicial de la página".

Comment: Perdón por pobre definición, me refiero a después de hacer login se entra en la página de inicio, en este caso tiene que ejecutar una serie de instrucciones, pero cuando se vuelva a esta home después de haber estado navegando por otras páginas del sitio debe de obviar la ejecución del código que ejecuto la primera vez.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una comprobación tal que:

```
    if(document.referrer == window.location.href) {
       ...
    }
```

Comprueba si la pagina anterior es la misma que en la que estás.

Tambien puedes usar las cookies: (si las borran, volverá a ejecutarse ésto)

```
window.onload = function () {
if (localStorage.get("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
    // Aqui el codigo para la primera vez

    localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
}
```

}

Si no, pon el codigo cuando hace login

Comment: Pues no me acordaba de la propiedad referrer del objecto document jejeje, muchas gracias por tu aporte, estoy siguiendo esa línea de investigación a ver si me soluciona el problema.